# Could not find add listener in PubNub in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, chat, pubnub

I am using Xcode 6.4 and trying to integrate the pubnub group chat functionality in my app. I followed this tutorial

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-ios-apps-getting-started-with-swift-and-pubnub/

I was able to do everything smoothly. But there was an error in the code. While writing this piece of code as given in the tutorial by pubnub I got this compilation error.
[image]

Is this method not available or I am doing anything wrong?

I have used the latest Pubnub sdk as stated in the blog using cocoapods.
What do I have to do in order to correct this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution. I forgot to add **PNObjectEventListener** in class Appdelegate

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PNObjectEventListener
```

Yet, this thing is not mentioned in the PubNub Blog

Comment: Blog was updated, it is definitely mentioned there now

Comment: yup, I got a mail from pubnub and they reported that they ll update the blog soon. Might be updated now.

Comment: Ah, I'm clarifying that the blog was _already_ updated at the time I posted that comment, no "might be" about it. But thanks for the feedback.